# Ajax call to change icons

Tags: javascript

I created below button

```
<button id="wishbtn" data-slug='{{ list.slug }}'><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
```

which calls an Ajax call.

```
$(document).on('click', '#wishbtn', function (e) {
    let el = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{% url 'listing:wishlist' %}",
        data: {
            title_slug: el.attr("data-slug"),
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('added to wishlist');
        }
    })
});
```

How do I change the class of `i` tag to `fas fa-heart` once the button is clicked. I tried using `this` keyword in success function to change its class `$(this).classList.replace('far', 'fas')` but it didn't work. I tried using `e.target.getElementsByTagName('i')[0].classList.replace('far', 'fas')` and again no hope.

Can you help me please, thank you.

Comment: this is a plain javascript question, using jQuery: $( this ).removeClass('far') and $( this ).addClass('fas')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#wishbtn', function(e) {
  let el = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "{% url 'listing:wishlist' %}",
    data: {
      title_slug: el.attr("data-slug"),
    },
    success: function() {
      let li = el.find('li')
      li.removeClass('far')
      li.addClass('fas')
    }
  })
});
```